# std::unordered_map with references as values does not work?

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, unordered

This code fails to compile in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class MyClass
{
public:
    char a;
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, MyClass&> MyMap;
    MyClass obj;
    obj.a = 'a';
    MyMap.emplace(1, obj);
    std::cout << MyMap[1].a;
}
```

With these error messages:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'MyClass &'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple    746

Error   2   error C2439: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::second' : member could not be initialized  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple    746
```

When I change it to pointers, it compiles fine. Are references invalid as value types in std::unordered_map?

The same code works fine with boost::unordered_map.

Comment: As a guess, is it because you are using emplace, which uses the given value in the constructor directly, but your class has no copy constructor?

Comment: @Ben how do _you_ copy a reference?

Comment: @sehe, ahhhh, never mind. I should read more carefully.

Answer (score 5):

References aren't copyable nor assignable. They're not supported as value types in any standard library container.

You can store `std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>` or, almost equivalently `MyClass*` though

Answer (score 0):

Container values must be copyable or moveable if you do much of anything with the container. Clearly, that is not possible with references. Therefore, your program is illegal.